# return statement from within using

Tags: c#-3.0

```
  using (IDbCommand command = new SqlCommand())
         {
             IDbDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
             DataSet ds = new DataSet();
             adapter.SelectCommand = command;
             command.Connection = _dataAccess.Connection;
             command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
             command.CommandText = "GetProcData";
             command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ProcID  ", procId));

            adapter.Fill(ds);
            return ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable();
         }
```

This returns an IEnumerable DataRow  The question is that since the return is within the using statement, will it property dispose of the IDBCommand?  I know I can easily refactor this so I change the scope of the DataSet outside of the using, but it is more of a wonder than anything else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this will work as expected with `IDbCommand` being properly disposed. The compiler will transform the using block to a `try-catch-finally`, where `Dispose` is invoked in the `finally` block.

Comment: That's what I thought as well, but I wasn't sure.  Thanks for the confirmation!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the DB Command will be disposed, so far so good.

You can get troubles with IEnumerables. Because the items *could* potentially be produced when getting them from the IEnumerable, not when creating the IEnumerable, that is the nature of it. So it depends on how `ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()` is implemented. It *could* wait with executing the command until you get the first item. This is in the calling code, outside of the using block. You'll get an error, because the command had been disposed.

This is probably not an issue here, but should always be considered when returning IEnumerables (or lambda expressions) from a using block:

```
using (A a = new A())
{
  return someItems.Select(x => a.Get(x));
}
```

When accessing the first item, `a` is already disposed and you get an error.

Answer (score 2):

The `IDbCommand` is disposed correctly. As a rule of thumb when returning from within a using statement you are fine to do so so long as:

1. The thing you are returning isn't in the clause of the using
   statement
2. The thing being returned isn't a reference created within the block of the using statement.

In the first case the using statement will dispose of the thing you are trying to return and in the second case the variable will go out of scope.

e.g.

```
//this is fine as result is createsd outside the scope of the block. 
bool result = false;
using (SmtpClient mailClient = new SmtpClient())
{
    try
    {
        mailClient.Send(...);
        result = true;
     } 
     catch(SmtpException)
     {
         result = false;
     } 
     finally 
     {
         return result;
     }
}
```

Here, the `using(){ ... }` statement is our friend. When we exit the block our `SmtpClient` is disposed, and the result condition will still exist for you to use.

However, say we are writing a WinForm app or WPF app and we wrap a using block around our data context then we create a problem as the context disappears before the control can consume it.

```
// this will fail when you bind the customers to a form control!
using (DbContext context = new DBContext())
{
context.Customers.Where(c => c.Name.Contains("Bob")).Load();
return context.Customers.Local;
}
```

Here, the `using(){ ... }` statement hurts us. As when we come to dataBind our customer to a GridView (or other such databound control) the fact that we have disposed of the `DbContext` will mean our form has nothing to bind to so it will throw an exception!

HTH

Answer (score 0):

The scope of your `IDbCommand` object is very clear: between the brackets `{` and `}`. As soon as your program flow exits from there, the object is disposed.